# Pass data into vuejs template

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2

I have a Laravel application with vuejs2 support. Im using the router component in the vuejs part. How can I send data like sessions from laravel to a vuejs template. In my blade template I use `<router-view ></router-view>` to call the vue router component. How can I add data.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried passing it as a prop? like `<router-view :myProp="myData" ></router-view>`

Comment: i have never worked with Laravel/Blade, but there might be some similar filters like in symfony's twig where you would be able to do something like this: `data(){ return {{ myVariable | json_encode | raw }} }`. so `data(){ return ...blade outputs json here... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page which you want to load using vuejs router component, add a script in the footer section of that page. And after using router push command, please refresh the whole page.

Keep a flag like: loading. At first, keep it true to view some initial message, and when you'll get axios response then make it false. Based on this flag, show the data that you get from axios response. And of course update the initially declared data after getting the axios response.
Example:

```
<script>
export default {
        data(){
            return {
                loading:true,
                // Others Data
            }
        },
        methods:{
            function_name (){
                this.$router.push('/');
                window.location.reload();
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            var _this = this;
            axios.get('/data').then(function (response) {
                //others data update
                _this.loading=false;
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And how can I update the content after the var `loading`is false?

Comment: We can use vuejs if-else.   

<p v-if="loading" >Loading ... </p>

<div v-else="loading">
 //Show Your data
</div>

Answer (score 1):

You can use axios to make a get request to your laravel app.

Example method:

```
data() {
   return {
      data: ''
   }
},
methods: {
    getData: function () {
      axios.get("/data")
      .then((response)  =>  {
        this.data = response.data;
      }, (error)  =>  {
      })
    }
  },
```

Note that you need to import axios in order to work:

```
import axios form 'axios'
```

Then you need to handle the request on the server side

Comment: I've already tried this with the problem that the template loads faster then the request. So I cant use the data on page load for things like session checking etc...

Comment: Maybe try using a method that returns a Promise, and then try to reach for the data? If you could show us some of your code, that would be great